# how to check if current_user is logged in through omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

If I have omniauth to allow users to log in using a provider such as facebook/twitter, how can I check to see if the current_user is logged in using omniauth?

I want to allow a code to run only if the current_user is logged in through omniauth.

Here's how my schema looks

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string    "name"
    t.string    "email"
    t.timestamp "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.timestamp "updated_at",                         :null => false
    t.string    "password_digest"
    t.string    "remember_token"

  end

 create_table "authentications", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "secret"
    t.string   "token"
  end
```

Controller

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def create
      @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])

      if @post.save
        if @post.check
          UserMailer.check_email(@user).deliver
        else
          flash[:success] = "Posted"
          Twitter::Client.new.update(@post.content) if logged_using_omniauth? request != nil
        end
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        @feed_items = []
        render 'static_pages/home'
      end
    end
```

Comment: Which gem are you using for authentication?

Comment: I'm using omniauth. I'm just trying to apply a code similar to `if current_user.?` for those logged in using omniauth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify it the following way:

```
def logged_using_omniauth? request
  res = nil
  omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  res = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid ↵  
  (omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid']) if omniauth
  res  
end
```

If the returned `authentication` is not `nil` then they logged in using omniauth.

Comment: for some reason, I'm getting a `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` error. This is how I am using it in my controller - `Twitter::Client.new.update(@post.content) if logged_using_omniauth?`

Comment: You need to pass the request object to it `logged_using_omniauth? request`

Comment: any idea how this can be fixed? `undefined method 'env' for true:TrueClass`

Comment: can you show me how are you calling the method again? (the current code)

Comment: removed the last part `!= nil`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28052/discussion-between-fmendez-and-user2159586)

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend to maintain a session to check if its logged in through omniauth.

#### in OmniauthCallbacksController

```
def method_name
 .......
 #if logged in set the session
 session[:logged_in_using_omniauth] = true
 .......
end
```

#### In ApplicationController

```
def logged_in_using_omniauth?
  session[:logged_in_using_omniauth].present?
end
```

And expose that method as helper method by:

```
helper_method :logged_in_using_omniauth?
```

Now use `logged_in_using_omniauth?` anywhere in controllers or views