# Devise - Omniauth – Hiding password fields if the user is signed in through Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, devise, helper

Using Devise with Omniauth I was successfully able to allow users to login with their Facebook accounts. With the help of the Omniauth [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) I was also able to disable having to put in a password when editing their account.

The current problem I'm faced with is hiding the password fields in my `registrations#edit` view if they signed up via Facebook. As a newcomer to both gems I'm still trying to adjust. So when it comes to setting up the necessary helper method(s) I'm sort've at a loss.

As instructed by the wiki here's what my Registrations controller looks like:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

    successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
      @user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
    else
      # remove the virtual current_password attribute
      # update_without_password doesn't know how to ignore it
      params[:user].delete(:current_password)
      @user.update_without_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
    end

    if successfully_updated
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case their password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private

  # check if we need password to update user data
  # ie if password or email was changed
  # extend this as needed
  def needs_password?(user, params)
    user.email != params[:user][:email] ||
      params[:user][:password].present? ||
      params[:user][:password_confirmation].present?
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my `registrations#edit` view:

```
<% provide :title, 'Edit Profile' %>

<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div><%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

After some extensive research I was able to find a [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325518/how-to-check-if-user-is-signed-in-with-omniauth) that inderictly answered what I was looking for in terms of *hiding* the input fields (second to last comment in the question). The only problem is that for some reason it triggers a password validation error despite it not being there...

```
   <div>
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>

  <% if user_signed_in? && !current_user.provider == 'facebook' %>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email %>
    </div>

    <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
      <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
    <% end %>

    <div>
      <%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
      <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching through the site I have FINALLY found out how to get this to work.

My first order of business was to to use the first code example for the registrations controller from this [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)

```
  def update
    # For Rails 4
    account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
    # For Rails 3
    # account_update_params = params[:user]

    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if account_update_params[:password].blank?
      account_update_params.delete("password")
      account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case their password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
```

Next was adding a method to override the validation for the user's current password just above the code above. Special thanks to Lauri Laine for her answer in this post: [Editing Users With Devise and Omniauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436232/editing-users-with-devise-and-omniauth)

```
  # Overwrite update_resource to let users to update their user without giving their password
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    if current_user.provider == "facebook"
      params.delete("current_password")
      resource.update_without_password(params)
    else
      resource.update_with_password(params)
    end
  end
```

Lastly I had to add `:current_password` as a virtual attribute to my user model and everything worked!

```
attr_accessor :current_password
```

Hopefully this helps anyone who has/will encounter this problem. I know it had me stumped for a minute but glad I was able to figure it all out. Will be testing this soon in conjunction with omniauth's twitter gem.

Comment: Nice write up and solution.  Good job.

Comment: This was the best solution that I found, I had some trouble shooting with your solution and I could not get it working. Thanks anywat. Fabrizio
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20737719/7295772

Comment: For the record, the method `update_resource` is not the default registration controller method `update`, it's another method (rails 6, devise 4.7.1).

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're saying fully.

Answer (score 0):

THe is a different approach possible.

From this page:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/views/devise
I have copied **shared** and **session** folders to

> app/views/devise/

After that, I was able to edit the views and hide whatever I wanted.