# Devise Edit User Not Saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

So I know there are like roughly half a million questions about bypassing the devise password requirement for editing  user if they authenticated through Facebook. I promise I have read at least 75% of them and still can't figure this out.

Basically, I have followed [Carl Edward & Laurie Laine's SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341541/devise-omniauth-hiding-password-fields-if-the-user-is-signed-in-through-face)  to create a registrations controller for Devise that will allow me to bypass the password validation if the user is editing their account and user is logged in from Facebook. With the following code, it finally doesn't throw an error but none of my updated attributes are saving.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    if current_user.provider == "facebook"
      params.delete("current_password")
      resource.update_without_password(params)
    else
      resource.update_with_password(params)
    end
  end

  def update
    account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)


    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if account_update_params[:password].blank?
      account_update_params.delete("password")
      account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)
      @user.update(account_update_params)
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      update_resource(@user,account_update_params)
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case their password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

I literally can't figure out what I am doing wrong but everytime I try to update my user profile as a logged in user authenticated by Facebook, nothing changes on my profile or when i query the database in my console.

Comment: Why do you call @user.update(account_update_params) after  @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)? update_attributes() is just an alias for update().

Comment: I added that because it wouldn't save and I thought that might make it start saving the updated attributes. I will take it out. Thanks! Any idea why it isn't saving?

Comment: What do you see in the log when saving user?

Comment: ` User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: `#column_for_attribute` will return a null object for non-existent columns in Rails 5. Use `#has_attribute?` if you need to check for an attribute's existence. (called from block in _app_views_devise_registrations_edit_html_erb___2743138430619144028_70258934707800 at views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:14)
  Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (19.4ms)
Completed 200 OK `

Comment: basically it's just the same deprecation warning 3 times and then the get for the redirect

Comment: It looks like smth in account_update_params hash makes the user object invalid. Try to play with rails console to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out it turns out that even though the necessary attributes were in my Devise parameter sanitizer I had  misnamed the :account_update parameters as :update.

BEFORE(not working):

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit({ roles: [] }, :name,:email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:update) { |u| u.permit({ roles: [] }, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar,:current_password, :about,:user, :name) }
  end
end
```

AFTER(working):

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit({ roles: [] }, :name,:email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit({ roles: [] }, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar,:current_password, :about,:user, :name) }
  end
end
```